# Show that if A is similar to $B$ and $A$ is nonsingular, then $B$ must also be nonsingular and $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are similar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I know that if B is similar to A, then B = $S^{-1}*A*S$, but I'm not sure where to go from there...

Comment: Hint: Take the inverse of both sides.

Comment: So $B^{-1}$ = $S$ * $A^{-1}$ * $S^{-1}$? Can I conclude anything from that?

Comment: And don't I need to find a way to prove the inverse of B exists first?

Comment: You conclude that $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are similar.  But, yes, you do need to first prove that $B$ is nonsingular.

Comment: No, there's nothing to prove. $B$ is a product of invertible matrices, hence it is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
The determinant is multiplicative. Restricted to the groups of invertible $n\times n$ matrices, it is a group homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is nonsingular, or invertible, then there exists a $B^{-1}$. So we try $B^{-1}=(S^{-1}AS)^{-1}=S^{-1}A^{-1}S$ and thus see that it is indeed nonsingular and that $B^{-1}$ is similar to $A^{-1}$.